# Find a 3 x 3 matrix B such that -3 is an eigenvalue of BA.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For this question, matrix A is as follows:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -1 & 0 \\
    2 & -3 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
.$$

I have found the eigenvalues of A; however, how do I find matrix B without guessing until I find the correct eigenvalue of $-3$? Is there a more systematic way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying $A$ by $$B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$ will switch the first two rows of $A$ so the product is an upper triangular matrix,

and it will multiply the third row by $3,$ so $-3$ is an element on the diagonal and thus an eigenvalue.

Comment: Thank you for the succinct explanation.

Comment: You’re welcome, and thank you for the “acceptance”